# Delphi SOAP server wsdl not refreshing

Tags: delphi, iis, wsdl

I have written a SOAP server and client to consume the services in Delphi XE2. The SOAP server executable is installed on a development Windows 8.1 PC running IIS and also a Windows 2003 Server (also IIS). Everything has been going ok except I have just added another service(method?) to my SOAP server and it won't show up in the WSDL after deploying the exe.

If I browse to the services executable (using firefox) e.g. 
`192.168.2.64:8080/mysoapservices/MySOAPServer.exe` or `192.168.2.64:8080/mysoapservices/MySOAPServer.exe/SOAP/IASOAPServer`

Then I can see the new method listed, but if I look at the `WSDL`

```
192.168.2.64:8080/mysoapservices/MySOAPServer.exe/WSDL/IASOAPServer
```

then it isn't in the XML definition. So, when I import the WSDL via `Delphi/Component/Import WSDL` it is missing my new method.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you looking at ASOAPServer.exe instead of MySOAPServer.exe?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't have the real links in there (confidentiality agreement with the people I'm working for), that is just a typing error on my behalf. The paths should all be identical, sorry.